# How to change tomcat server date?

Tags: date, tomcat, cron

I need to change tomcat server date in order to check whether my cron expression will be triggered on needed day and time or not. How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to change the date of the underlying OS. Tomcat has no separate clock. You also should restart the tomcat afterwards..

Answer (score 1):

Try to check in web.inf file if by any parameter is their from where you can change the date.
Otherwise as earlier comment change the system date and restart the server.